# DataGridView Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to check if the dataGridView CheckBox column is checked, and when I run the program it gives me this an error as:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

anyone to help?

C# code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < payRollDataGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   bool isCellChecked = (bool)payRollDataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;

   if (isCellChecked == true)
   {
   MessageBox.Show(payRollDataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "Cheked");
   }         
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: one of the .Cells[0] or .Cells[1] is null and has no value ...

Comment: That means is unchecked, but my aim is to select some of the Cells, not al the Cell, and Cell[1] is not null, it has the values.

Comment: which event are u executing this code like cellendedit, cellclick event

Comment: I check first the checkBox and press the Button

Comment: private void CheckBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < payRollDataGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                 bool isCellChecked = (bool)payRollDataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;

                    if (isCellChecked == true)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(payRollDataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "Cheked");

                    }
                
            }
        }

Comment: foreach(DataGridViewRow currentRow in payRollDataGrid.Rows)
{                
  if ((bool)currentRow.Cells[0].Value)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(currentRow.Cells[0].Value + "Cheked");
  } else if((bool)currentRow.Cells[1].Value)){ MessageBox.Show(currentRow.Cells[1].Value + "Cheked");                             }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow currentRow in payRollDataGrid.Rows)
{                
  if ((bool)currentRow.Cells[0].Value)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(currentRow.Cells[1].Value + "Cheked");
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to disable Adding

Comment: it seems like it is for only one column, but I have two column, the one at Cell[0](with CheckBox) and the other at Cell[1]. Now I need to check the Cell[0] and get the value of Cell[1]